# gdb watch a variable by address stop at where it cannot be modified

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

A program crashes. I use gdb to check, find that a private member of a instance is changed in a very weird way. This variable `refreshRank`,is only modified at line 283 and 286. I use gdb to watch `refreshRank` by watch its address, i.e., `watch *0x5555559ec278`. I get the address by `p &refreshRank` when I am in a member function of the class.
[image]
However, with `watch` command, gdb says that where `refreshRank` is modified is before line 594. But it cannot be modified! `refreshRank` is even not referenced in those lines, as `l` command gives.

```
Hardware watchpoint 1: *0x5555559ec278

Old value = 0
New value = 1
DRAMSim::MemoryController::update (this=0x5555559ec020) at MemoryController.cpp:594
594             newTransactionBank, transaction->data, dramsim_log);
(gdb) l
589                 totalReads[transaction->core]++;
590                }
591 
592            BusPacket *command = new BusPacket(bpType, transaction->address,
593             newTransactionColumn, newTransactionRow, newTransactionRank,
594             newTransactionBank, transaction->data, dramsim_log);
595 
596 
597 
598             commandQueue.enqueue(ACTcommand);
```

So I wonder, how can this happen? The variable is modified at a place which it cannot be.

Comment: Did you compile with optimizations enabled?  If so, it's quite common for the actual execution order to appear slightly out of step with the source when debugging.

Comment: Did you consider that you have just found the bug in your code? That the code changes a value that it should not change and, hence, must be incorrect?

Comment: @j6t Yes, it is incorrect, but I cannot find a line that changes its value. gdb says it changes, but those lines does not reference that variable.

Comment: @G.M. I compile all files with `-O0`, no optimization is enabled.

Comment: Then some code writes outside its memory bounds. The array access at line 589 looks like a candidate: it increments a value (old 0, new 1), and it uses an index that could be incorrect.

Comment: @j6t Yes, you are right! Thanks! `totalReads[transaction->core]++;`, `transaction->core` is too large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @j6t points out, the last line it executes, `totalReads[transaction->core]++;`, `transaction->core` is out of bound. And in the class definition:

```
uint64_t totalReads[NUM_CPU];
uint64_t totalPrefReads[NUM_CPU];
uint64_t totalWrites[NUM_CPU];


unsigned channelBitWidth;
unsigned rankBitWidth;
unsigned bankBitWidth;
unsigned rowBitWidth;
unsigned colBitWidth;
unsigned byteOffsetWidth;
int totalRead, totalWrite;

unsigned refreshRank;
```

Those two variables are close.